# Solving the trigonometric equation $2(1 + \sin \theta )\sin \theta =1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

I usually use guessing to solve equations with trigonometric functions. Yesterday, I came across an equation that I could not really write it in a helpful form to guess. My question is, how can I solve equation like that without WolframAlpha? I really want to learn a method to solve trigonometric equations without guessing.

Some of my tires to write in a form that allows me to guess an answer.
\begin{align}
2(1+\sin \theta )\sin \theta &= 1 \\
\sin \theta +\sin^2 \theta &= \frac{1}{2} \\
2\sin \theta +(1-\cos 2\theta ) &= 1 \\
2\sin \theta -\cos 2\theta &= 0 \\
2\sin \theta -\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta &= 0 \\
\end{align}

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Lord_Farin for the edit. My eyes got pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you have a quadratic in $\sin\theta$ (second line)

$$\sin(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} \iff \sin^2\theta + \sin \theta - 1/2 = 0$$

Set $x = \sin\theta$

$$x^2 + x - 1/2 = 0$$

$$x = \sin \theta = \dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt3}2$$

However, note that $\sqrt 3 > 1\implies -1-\sqrt3<-2\implies \dfrac{-1-\sqrt 3}2 < -1$

Since we need $\theta$ such that $ \; |\sin \theta| \leq 1$, we want only $\sin\theta = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt 3}2$

Comment: Tricky magical $x$.

Comment: I should have thought about it!. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, user98456!

Comment: @amWhy: Excellent feedback - doesn't get much better than that! +1

Answer (score 4):

So, $2\sin^2\theta+2\sin\theta-1=0$

Using the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Derivation_of_the_quadratic_formula) of Quadratic Eqaution,

$\sin\theta =\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{2^2-4(2)(-1)}}{2\cdot2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt3}2$

But as $\sqrt3>1\implies -1-\sqrt3<-2\implies \frac{-1-\sqrt3}2<-1$

For real $\theta,-1\le \sin\theta\le1$
$\implies \sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt3-1}2$